# mocha test not recognizing *.d.ts declarations

Tags: node.js, typescript, mocha.js

I'm having a problem with configuring mocha to support my typescript code. I have some types defined in a `global.d.ts` placed in a `src` folder of the project root.

When i run `mocha -r ts-node/register test/**/*.ts` i receive the following errors:

```
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/mediator/index.ts:5:28 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'DomainEvent'.

5     [key: string]: (event: DomainEvent) => Promise<void>
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~
src/mediator/index.ts:11:57 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'DomainEvent'.

11     registerHandler(eventType: string, handler: (event: DomainEvent) => Promise<void>) {
                                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~
src/mediator/index.ts:18:37 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'IntegrationEvent'.

18     async publish(integrationEvent: IntegrationEvent) {
```

When I run `ts-node ./src/app.ts` the app runs fine. Does anyone know what i am doing wrong?

My tsconfig (I suspect the problem is related to this):

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "target": "es6",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "dist",
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "@mediator": ["src/mediator"],
            "*": [
                "node_modules/*"
            ]
        },
        "typeRoots": [
            "./global"
        ]
    },
    "include": [
        "**/*.ts"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

include your `global.d.ts` in `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
  },
  "include": [
    "./global.d.ts",
    "./src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: This does not seem to solve my problem. I am still getting `Property 'status' does not exist on type 'SyntaxError'.` which I extended in global.d.ts and it works when I run node.

Comment: In the end I used `ts-node: { files: true }` but I also had to fix the global.d.ts which probably would have fixed your example.

Comment: I have the same problem and this doesn't work. The problem does not exist when compiling with tsc, it **only** occurrs with `mocha`.

Answer (score 0):

@acrazing was very close, what worked for me is adding this to tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "files": [
    "./global.d.ts",
  ]
}
```

NB: Wildcards/globbing does not work, only individual files can be given :(

However, this breaks eslint since it now thinks that *only this file* should be included for linting... So it may not be a full solution if you use `eslint`.